# Find objects by id using arrays in js

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, html-table

In my code, I have an 8x8 table with each `<td>` having an id of two numbers ranging from 0-7 (i.e. "0, 0", "2, 5", etc). What I need is to make a function that when I click on a `<td>` it gives me the first and the second numbers of the id.
I thought maybe I can do this with arrays, but I don't know how to extract the two separate numbers from the id in the first place.

I am a beginner in javascript/html, so an explanation with the answers will be very helpful!

Comment: please clarify: every `<td>` tag has a uniqe id? or has a inner text contain 2 numbers?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to get all `<td>` tags, then looping through them and setting an `onclick` function:

```
var cells = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
for (let index = 0; index < cells.length; index++) {
    var cell = cells.item(index);
    cell.onclick = function (e) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

In the `onclick` function, you have the click event that contains the target html element(the `<td>`) now we just need to extract numbers:

```
var text = e.target.innerText;                
var result = text.split(","); // splited as text not number
var n1, n2;
n1 = Number(result[0]); // casting text to int(number)
n2 = Number(result[1]); // casting text to int(number)
```

where `n1` and `n2` are extracted numbers.

Here is complete code:

```
var cells = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
for (let index = 0; index < cells.length; index++) {
    var cell = cells.item(index);
    cell.onclick = function (e) {
        var text = e.target.innerText;                
        var result = text.split(",");
        var n1, n2;
        n1 = Number(result[0]);
        n2 = Number(result[1]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to W3:

> The id value must contain at least one character, and must **not** contain whitespace (spaces, tabs, etc.).

So if you are setting the id through `<td id="yourId">`, then `yourId` cannot be `0, 0`.

To solve that problem you can use an id of `xy` where your two numbers are `x` and `y`, assuming they range from 0 to 7.

```html
<td onclick="clicked(event)" id="25">click me</td>
```

Then you can get the first and second characters of the id.

```js
function clicked(event) {
  const id = event.target.id;
  const x = parseInt(id.charAt(0));
  const y = parseInt(id.charAt(1));
  console.log(x);
  // 2
  console.log(y);
  // 5
}
```